# JQuery keyword "this" does not get attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

I am playing around with the JQuery keyword this.

I have come across something I do not understand.
Here is my code:

```
<body>  
    <a id="link_1">jQuery.com</a>￼

    <!-- adding JQUERY -->  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>            
    <!-- my JavaScript -->      
    <script>
      $("a").attr("href", "target_1");  
      $("a").attr("new_attribute", "new_attribute_value");

      $(function ($) {          
        $("a").mouseenter(function(){
                alert(this.id);
                alert(this.href);
                alert(this.new_attribute);          
         });        
       });  
    </script> 
</body>
```

I want JQuery to return the id, href and my new_attribute as an alert message.

I can call the id on the keyword 'this' (with this.id) and it works as expected.
I can also call the href on the keyword this (with this.href) and it works as expected (even though I set the value of href with JQuery only (an not inline)).

However with the new attribute "new_attribute" this kind of set & get does not work as expected.

my question: **What am I doing wrong? Is it only possible to call 'certain /limited' attributes on the keyword 'this'.**

Comment: Non–standard attributes aren't necessarily reflected in same–named properties. IE does it, but not all others. Change *attr* to *prop*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `new_attribute` is not a valid attribute.

Some built in attributes are mapped to properties, and when you do

```
this.id
```

you're really getting the `id` property, not the attribute, as that would be

```
this.getAttribute('id')
```

you could do

```
this.getAttribute('new_attribute')
```

but you should really be using `data-*` attributes, and not make up your own, but jQuery's `data()` maps data internally and doesn't add attributes, but in your case that's probably what you want, just store arbitrary data on the element

```
$("a").attr("href", "target_1");  
$("a").data("new_attribute", "new_attribute_value");

$(function ($) {          
    $("a").mouseenter(function(){
            alert(this.id);
            alert(this.href);
            alert( $(this).data('new_attribute') );
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In this context `this` points to HTMLAnchorElement object, and the problem here is the difference between HTMLElement [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) and their properties. Simply saying, attributes are rendered as a part of HTML, and used for additional object declarative configuration from the side of HTML markup.

On the other hand, there are properties of the object, which not always have corresponding attributes. Sometimes they do, but in most cases - they don't.

You can set any arbitrary attribute to HTMLElement like you did with `new_attribute`, but this custom attribute value will not become an object property. So reading such custom attribute as property will yield `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

"this" refers to the DOM element (try console.log(this)). An Element exposes its id attribute, as you can see here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element

Since it is an A element, it also exposes its href attribute. But it never knows your custom attribute. So it can't expose it.

Try this in you event handler :

```
var $this = $(this);
alert($this.attr('new_attribute'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat `this` as a selector, so write it like `$(this)`

Comment: If i change my code according to your answer, then I only get the return value of "undefined" in all 3 alerts.

Comment: Forgot to say, you can't access properties directly like `id`, to get that, do `$(this).attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you set an attribute with the `attr()` method but you're querying (getting) it with a call to an equivalent method to jQuery's`prop()`.

Since this is a non standard attribute, the main interface for the anchor `<a>` element `HTMLAnchorElement` or other interfaces that it inherits from in the DOM don't have/implement a `new_attribute` property in place, your `this.new_attribute` would always return `undefined`.

However, if you'd like to keep experimenting with the `this` keyword, you could try something along these lines `this.attributes['new_attribute']`and you won't have any unpleasant surprises in your coding excursion anymore :)